# Select which has max date or latest date

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Here are two tables.

SCHOOL_STAFF

```
SCHOOL_CODE + STAFF_TYPE_NAME + LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME + PERSON_ID
=================================================================
ABE           Principal         24-JAN-13               111222
ABE           Principal         09-FEB-12               222111
```

PERSONS

```
PERSON_ID + NAME
=================
111222      ABC
222111      XYZ
```

Here is my oracle query.

```
SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME) AS LAST_UPDATE, SCHOOL_CODE, PERSON_ID
FROM SCHOOL_STAFF
WHERE STAFF_TYPE_NAME='Principal'
GROUP BY SCHOOL_CODE, PERSON_ID
ORDER BY SCHOOL_CODE;
```

which gives this results

```
LAST_UPDATE SCHOOL_CODE PERSON_ID
===========+===========+=========
24-JAN-13   ABE         111222
09-FEB-12   ABE         222111
```

I want to select the first one for the school which has latest date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your current query is not giving the desired result because you are using a `GROUP BY` clause on the `PERSON_ID` column which has a unique value for both entries.  As a result you will return both rows.

There are a few ways that you can solve this.  You can use a subquery to apply the aggregate function to return the `max(LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME)` for each `SCHOOL_CODE`:

```
select s1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
  s1.SCHOOL_CODE,
  s1.PERSON_ID
from SCHOOL_STAFF s1
inner join
(
  select max(LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME) LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
    SCHOOL_CODE
  from SCHOOL_STAFF
  group by SCHOOL_CODE
) s2
  on s1.SCHOOL_CODE = s2.SCHOOL_CODE
  and s1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME = s2.LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19fa0/2)

Or you can use use a [windowing function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php) to return the rows of data for each school with the most recent `LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME`:

```
select SCHOOL_CODE, PERSON_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME
from
(
  select SCHOOL_CODE, PERSON_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
    row_number() over(partition by SCHOOL_CODE 
                        order by LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME desc) seq
  from SCHOOL_STAFF
  where STAFF_TYPE_NAME='Principal'
) d
where seq = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19fa0/1)

This query implements [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) which assigns a unique number to each row in the partition of `SCHOOL_CODE` and placed in a descending order based on the `LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME`.

As a side note, the JOIN with aggregate function is not exactly the same as the `row_number()` version.  If you have two rows with the same event time the JOIN will return both rows, while the `row_number()` will only return one.  If you want to return both with a windowing function, then consider using the `rank()` windowing function instead as it will return ties:

```
select SCHOOL_CODE, PERSON_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME
from
(
  select SCHOOL_CODE, PERSON_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
    rank() over(partition by SCHOOL_CODE 
                        order by LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME desc) seq
  from SCHOOL_STAFF
  where STAFF_TYPE_NAME='Principal'
) d
where seq = 1;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5594/1)

Comment: Thanks, I find the inner join to a subquery table (example 1 above) to be the most intuitive.. and doesn't require me to learn what _partition by_ is all about.  

Here is a look at a similar syntax to example 1:   
select oT.dateField, oT.siteID, oT.field1, oT.field2, oT.field3, 
from **originalTable** as **oT**
inner join
(select max(dateField) as newestDate,  siteID
from originalTable
group by siteID
 ) as newTable
on oT.siteID = newTable.site_ID and oT.dateField = newTable.newestDate
order by oT.siteID asc

To me, that better explains what's happening in the subquery.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody has taken advantage of window functions beyond row_number()

Here's some data to play with:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHOOL_STAFF
(
LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME VARCHAR(20),
SCHOOL_CODE VARCHAR(20),
PERSON_ID VARCHAR(20),
STAFF_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO SCHOOL_STAFF VALUES ('24-JAN-13', 'ABE', '111222', 'Principal');
INSERT INTO SCHOOL_STAFF VALUES ('09-FEB-12', 'ABE', '222111', 'Principal');
```

The OVER() clause creates a window for which you will define your aggregate groups.  In this case, I am only partitioning on the SHOOL_CODE, so we will see the FIRST_VALUE, which will come from LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME, grouped by SCHOOL_CODE, and in the order of LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME by descending order.  This value will be applied to the entire column for each SCHOOL_CODE.

It is important to pay close attention to your partitioning and ordering in the over() clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 FIRST_VALUE(LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY SCHOOL_CODE ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME DESC) AS LAST_UPDATE
,FIRST_VALUE(SCHOOL_CODE)           OVER (PARTITION BY SCHOOL_CODE ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME DESC) AS SCHOOL_CODE
,FIRST_VALUE(PERSON_ID)             OVER (PARTITION BY SCHOOL_CODE ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME DESC) AS PERSON_ID
FROM SCHOOL_STAFF
WHERE STAFF_TYPE_NAME = 'Principal'
ORDER BY SCHOOL_CODE
```

Returns:

```
24-JAN-13   ABE 111222
```

This should eliminate your need for GROUP BY and Subqueries for the most part.  You will want to make sure to include DISTINCT though.

Comment: This is nice, but is there a way to avoid repeating the over clause for all columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
select LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME as LAST_UPDATE,
  SCHOOL_CODE,
  PERSON_ID
from SCHOOL_STAFF
WHERE STAFF_TYPE_NAME='Principal'
AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME = (SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME)
                            FROM SCHOOL_STAFF s2
                            WHERE PERSON_ID = s2.PERSON_ID)
```

Comment: Instead of posting *just* code, you should attempt to explain how this answers the question; and potentially what the OP was doing incorrectly.